# Convert Java AWT code to Android

Tags: java, android, awt

I developed code in Java using AWT.  Now I would like to use that code in Android. While I used that code in Android, error is showing at "graphics". Here is part of code.

```
public void fixBox(Graphics g,int x,int y,int w,int h,Color c)
    {
        g.setColor(c);
        g.fillRect(x,y,w,h);
    }
```

How to convert it to, and use it in, Android?

Answer (score 0):

Android has his own UI library :) so you need to write the code with the android UI standard 
you cannot use swing or awt in android UI :)

For more details about android and java this is a important information you need to know 
The difference between Dalvik Virtual Machine and Java Virtual Machine and you'll get the all the points

Comment: Thanks for your help.Please suggest good link to know more difference b/w DVM and JVM